# Renaming and editing a ChiP-seq bed file

Tags: awk, sed

I have around 80 bed files with 1st 3 columns (example : X2_example.bed, where X2 is the gene name) and I want to add a 4th column with gene name and rename the file (example attached: X2_example_edited.bed, Y2_example_edited.bed and so on..), and then merge these files together to create 1 bed file.

I can add the 4th column with gene name and save the file with a different name with the code

```
 sed 's/$/\tX2/' < X2_example.bed  > X2_example_edited.bed
```

This is the generated bed file

```
chr17   42276210    42276219    X2
chr17   42297938    42297947    X2
chr17   42276210    42276219    X2
chr17   42297938    42297947    X2
```

But I have to do this separately for each bed file. This there a way I can extract the gene name from the name of the file (eg. X2 from X2_example.bed) and then add that to the 4th column of the bed file and save it as X2_example_edited.bed.

I can extract the gene name from the file name 
`echo "X2_example.bed" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $1}`

However, as I have too many files I am looking for a way to generate a loop to automate this.

Also I need to merge all the generated bed file which I can do by

```
cat *_edited.bed >output.bed
```

However, I am having an error (see attached example: output.bed), the last line of 1st file and 1st line of next file are on same line.

```
chr3    18467066    18467075    Y2
chr17   42276210    42276219    X2
```

I know this must be a very basic thing, but I am new to this analysis and have limited knowledge.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can try with `awk`

```
for file in *.bed; do 
    awk '{split(FILENAME,a,"_"); print $0, a[1]}' "$file" 
done > output.bed.all
```

Comment: @Debbie miswriting, is `awk`